# Fetching whole partition with owb

Tags: oracle, oracle-warehouse-builder

Am working on a OWB project. My sources are tables partitioned monthly. I have a control_table that holds the last run date. I want to use OWB to fetch a whole partition (monthly) data into a landing table, enjoying the performance. Kindly assist in coming up with the way **OWB treats partition as its source**. 
Thanks.

Comment: My default attempt is to load the whole table. Dont seems to get how to add just partition in the owb table metadata.

Comment: I'd just query the whole table and use a WHERE clause to select the correct month - Oracle should then use only the matching partition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea.

Just implement you logic in OWB. If partitions are available, OWB/ Oracle will use them to get any possible benefits.

If the partitions are not used, there should be a issue with the partitioning strategy. Try to correct the partitioning strategy.

Partitioning should be transparent.